# Curved Container style double flutter

Tags: flutter

i looking for this particular kind of curved container. Thank you for help.

[image]

Code example :

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16,left: 16,top: 16,bottom: 64),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.80,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-32,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
 
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(0),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.4),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(32.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(0)),
       
 
        ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: which part you are trying to get black or white ,on your snippet I see `Colors.blue`. try to play with Path with brazier-Curve

Comment: did you did it? I am also trying but cant find the answer